# MySQL ignore warning on a single function

Tags: mysql

I'd like to update some text rows to normalize a date format.  Since the source format might be any one of a few different formats, I'm extracting it like this:

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.comment, '(?<=Date: )[0-9/]+') AS date_str,
    COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE((SELECT date_str), '%m/%d/%Y'), NULL) AS converted_a,
    COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE((SELECT date_str), '%m/%d/%y'), NULL) AS converted_b,
    COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE((SELECT date_str), '%d/%m/%Y'), NULL) AS converted_c,
    COALESCE((SELECT converted_a), (SELECT converted_b), (SELECT converted_c)) AS new_date_str
FROM my_table t
```

This works fine. I then try to update rows:

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT
        t.id,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.comment, '(?<=Date: )[0-9/]+') AS date_str,
        COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE((SELECT date_str), '%m/%d/%Y'), NULL) AS converted_a,
        COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE((SELECT date_str), '%m/%d/%y'), NULL) AS converted_b,
        COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE((SELECT date_str), '%d/%m/%Y'), NULL) AS converted_c,
        COALESCE((SELECT converted_a), (SELECT converted_b), (SELECT converted_c)) AS new_date_str
    FROM my_table t
)
    JOIN my_table t2 USING (id)
SET t2.comment = REPLACE(t2.comment, date_str, new_date_str)
```

However, since `STR_TO_DATE` issues a warning, the update fails:

> Incorrect datetime value: '15/09/2014' for function str_to_date

I know that I can workaround this issue by writing `UPDATE IGNORE` *but I don't want to ignore all warnings* - only the warnings issued by `STR_TO_DATE`.

**Is there a way to ignore or suppress only the warnings coming from the `STR_TO_DATE` function, while still respecting any other warnings that may come up?**

Comment: One option is to delegate it to a stored routine (function) that uses a handler.

Comment: @wchiquito - thanks.  sounds overly complicated for my use case but I'd be open to trying if you want to post an answer detailing your approach.

Comment: See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HcNe8GuK).

Comment: @wchiquito - thanks! that's really cool.  I've never really delved into sql functions before and though I'd hoped for a simpler solution, this does indeed do what I wanted.